# Mvc Core Dynamically bind Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am wondering if it is possible to bind a configuration section to an object dynamically. Normally to bind a configuration section we would write code like this:

```
var section = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyCustomSection));
services.Configure<MyCustomSection>(o => secto.Bind(o));
```

I am wondering if its possible to do it without declaring the type `<MyCustomSection>`.

```
//This doesn't work, just trying to show you how I would like to do it
services.Configure(MyType, o => section.Bind(o));
```

For example, if I wish to bind injection I can do it like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDateTime, SystemDateTime>();
```

But I can also do it in a dynamic way such as this:

```
services.AddTransient(Type1, Type2));
```

Is the same possible for `services.Configure`? I looked at method parameters but it doesn't seem to support it. Just wondering if there is another way or maybe I'm just overlooking something?

EDIT:

```
services.AddSingleton(p =>   
{
    var type = new MySection();
    Configuration.GetSection("MySection").Bind(type);
    return type;
});
```

Then I call it in a class like this:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(IOptions<MySection> section)
    {
        var finalValue = section.Value;
    }
}
```

`finalValue` is always null;

Answer (score 3):

First off, all `Configure` does is

1. bind the configuration section to a particular type and
2. register that type with the service collection, such that it may be injected directly.

Therefore, if `Configure` doesn't have an overload to do what you want, you can simply jump down to the individual tasks, i.e.

```
services.AddSingleton(p =>
{
    var config = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    Configuration.GetSection("Foo").Bind(config);
    return config;
}
```

Comment: I tried following your example and it always gives me a null value. I have updated my question with the code I tried based on your example. Do you know if I've missed something?

Comment: I imagine it's some issue with how you're getting the `SectionName`, i.e. that is probably returning `null` or something, such that it's not actually find a section to bind to. FWIW, I tested this code in my own project, and can confirm it works.

Comment: The issues is that I have been trying to call IOptions<MyType> as opposed to just MyType. This solution ultimately gives me dynamic binding, but it doesn't go through `IOptions` anymore.

Comment: You don't need `IOptions` anyways. The only value is in `IOptionsSnapshot`, but I was unfortunately unable to find a way to make that work. So, you don't get reload with this method, but depending in your application that may not matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you really wanted to, you could use reflection to call `services.Configure<TOptions>()` with a dynamic generic type argument at runtime. However, there may be a simpler way to get your desired result (using `IOptions<>`) using some modification of Chris's answer.

Use it like so:

`services.Configure(MyType, o => { var castObj = (MyType)o; section.Bind(castObj); });`

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class MyServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection Configure(this IServiceCollection services, Type type, Action<object> configureOptions)
        {
            // Static type that contains the extension method
            var extMethodType = typeof(OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions);

            // Find the overload for Configure<TOptions>(IServiceCollection, Action<TOptions>)
            // This could be more specific to make sure that all type arguments are exactly correct.
            // As it stands, this returns the correct overload but future updates to OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions
            // may add additional overloads which will require this to be updated.
            var genericConfigureMethodInfo = extMethodType.GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name == "Configure")
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    Method = m,
                    Params = m.GetParameters(),
                    Args = m.GetGenericArguments() // Generic Type[] (ex [TOptions])
                })
                .Where(m => m.Args.Length == 1 && m.Params.Length == 2
                    && m.Params[0].ParameterType == typeof(IServiceCollection))
                .Select(m => m.Method)
                .Single();

            var method = genericConfigureMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);

            // Invoke the method via reflection with our converted Action<objct> delegate
            // Since this is an extension method, it is static and services is passed
            // as the first parameter instead of the target object
            method.Invoke(null, new object[] { services, configureOptions });

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the answer is correct, however, it is such an overkill haha. I was really hoping there was a built-in way I'm missing out on.

Comment: You may find a cleaner way to inject the configured options via `IOptions` if you looked at the open source implementation of `.Configure<>()`, but this solution should work just fine. I didn't do any tests of this with type inheritance so there may be something overlooked there